# C++ Read file in 2D array

Tags: c++

I'm almost frustrated with this program. I have a file that contains 100 records but, my output will not go beyond 17 including the header. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

char medRecord[100][8];
int header, person;

int main()
{

    ifstream in("fakedata.txt");
    if(!in){
        cout << "Cannot open file. \n";
        return 1;
    }

in.read((char *) &medRecord, sizeof medRecord);

for(person = 0; person < 100; person++)
     for(header = 0; header < 8; header++)
cout << medRecord[person][header] << "";

return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Number,Gender,GivenName,Surname,Birthday,BloodType,Pounds,FeetInches
1,male,Joseph,Doody,1/10/1968,A-,179.5,5' 7"
2,male,Robert,King,8/17/1985,A+,203.1,5' 10"
3,male,Richard,Murphy,3/18/1944,O+,235.6,6' 1"
4,female,Caroline,Acosta,5/27/1959,B+,145.4,5' 8"
5,male,John,Capps,12/18/1967,O+,186.6,5' 9"
6,female,Stephanie,Guidry,3/25/1981,O+,177.8,5' 6"
7,female,Janet,Kimmel,2/23/1977,A+,161.3,5' 7"
8,male,Jerrell,Wright,8/4/1929,B+,140.6,5' 9"
9,female,Cheryl,Johnson,12/8/1972,A+,128.7,5' 1"
10,female,Sandra,Gonzalez,6/1/1974,A+,171.4,5' 9"
11,male,Kevin,Noel,9/30/1939,O+,212.1,5' 6"
12,female,Krysta,Booth,7/9/1940,O+,173.1,5' 3"
13,male,Sam,Clark,7/5/1979,A+,162.4,5' 9"
14,male,James,Graves,8/15/1959,A+,235.0,5' 8"
15,male,Elton,Fink,6/30/1937,A+,198.4,5' 5"
16,male,Robert,Daniels,10/14/1969,Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Where is the code that does the outputting?

Comment: Tip : your output right now is exactly 800 characters, which strangely matches some part of your code.

Comment: So I'm looking to output foe the full 100 lines. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `medRecord` array contains 800 characters.  The outputted text contains 783 characters, one line short (or less) of 800.  So, sight unseen, what you're probably doing is trying to read the entire file into `medRecord`,  and the readin or outputting stops when it gets filled up.

I counted by cutting/pasting into Open Office--if the newlines aren't getting counted properly, then 783 + 17 = 800 and there you go.

Comment: +1 for debugging code without seeing code. It's like zen programming

Comment: @greedybuddha Raymond Chen would call it psychic debugging, as in 'My psychic powers tell me that <mistake>'

Comment: @Patashu, I love it when he does that.